# How to check action is called by twig renderer or not

Tags: php, symfony

An action can be called by HTTP request or it can be called by Twig renderer function.

```
{{ render(controller('MohebifarPaymentBundle:Default:shetab')) }}
```

I want to detect when twig renderer called the action and do somewhat in action.

```
public function shetabAction() {
    ...

    if(ACTION_IS_CALLED_BY_RENDERER) {

        // Action is called by Twig renderer

    } else { 

        // Action is called by HTTP request

    }

    ...
}
```

Is there any statement to check that ?

Comment: Who did vote down !?? Why ?!? What's wrong with my question ?!

Comment: I've upvote for you, I'm interesting into a solution too, and your question is clear

Comment: @PerroinThibault Thank you ! I really need it !

Comment: Maybe a look into Listeners or Events can help you